# Insert only when auto-increment id is not equal 6(for example)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 3 fields: Id(PK,AI), Name(varchar(36)), LName(varchar(36)).
I have to insert name and last name, Id inserts automatically because of it's constraints,

Is There a way to Jump id auto increment value when it reaches 6?

for instance do this 7 times:

Insert Into table(Name, LName) Values ('name1', 'lname1') "And jump id to 7 if it is going to be 6"
It may sound stupid to do this but I have the doubt.

Also Jump and do not record id 6.
record only, 1-5, 7,8,9 and so on

**What I want to achieve starts from a Union:**

```
Select * From TableNames
Union All
Select * From TableNames_general
```

In the TableNames_general I assign it's first value so that when the user sees the table for the first time it will be displayed the record I inserted.

The problem comes when the user inserts a new record, if the Id of the inserted record is the same as the one I have inserted it will be duplicated, that is why I want to achieve when the users inserts one record and if the last insert id already exists just jump that record. this is because I must have different ids due to its relationship among child tables.

Comment: This is tagged both MySQL and SQL Server. MySQL provides `AUTO_INCREMENT` property. The SQL Server equivalent is `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Any answer about the question?

Comment: It's not possible to influence the behavior of `AUTO_INCREMENT` or `IDENTITY` to "skip" a particular value. There's workarounds that will allow you to get a row inserted with an id value of 7 instead of a 6, but those require manual workarounds to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `IDENTITY` behavior, they don't change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity column generate values for you, And its best left this way, You have the ability to insert specific values in Identity column but its best left alone and let it generate values for you.

Imagine you have inserted a value explicitly in an identity column and then later on Identity column generates the same value for you, you will end up with duplicates.

If you want to have your input in that column then why bother with identity column anyway ??

Well this is not the best practice but you can jump to a specific number by doing as follows:

**MS SQL SERVER 2005 and Later**

```
-- Create test table
CREATE TABLE ID_TEST(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), VALUE INT)
GO

-- Insert values
INSERT INTO ID_TEST (VALUE) VALUES
(1),(2),(3)
GO

-- Set idnentity insert on to insert values explicitly in identity column
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ID_TEST ON;

INSERT INTO ID_TEST (ID, VALUE) VALUES
(6, 6),(8,8),(9,9)
GO

-- Set identity insert off
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ID_TEST OFF;
GO

-- 1st reseed the value of identity column to any smallest value in your table
-- below I reseeded it to 0
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('ID_TEST', RESEED, 0);
-- execute the same commad without any seed value it will reset it to the 
-- next highest idnetity value
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('ID_TEST', RESEED);
GO

-- final insert 
INSERT INTO ID_TEST (VALUE) VALUES
(10)
GO

-- now select data from table and see the gap
SELECT * FROM ID_TEST
```

Comment: I've just edited the question about the issue, is there a diferent way I can do?

Comment: Do not allow your users to add Ids, it is something you should control, take all the other information from users and let identity column decide or yourself, what ID should be assigned to the new record. You need to control this on application layer. Never let your user have a direct input in your database. a recipe for disaster :)

Comment: Initially your question was how to skip ids in identity column now you have come up with other requirements. I think you need to rethink and ask precisely what are you after possibly with some sample data and expected output with an example.

Comment: I do not know if I did not explained my self correctly, the users never insert ids they only insert i.e. name and lname. what I want todo is to insert the first record (from the admin) so that the user sees the record data(for instance I add for them the 1st record), then they can add their own records as normal (without inserting ids), the problem is that that table is a parent table that have child tables and when there is a duplicate in that parent table i will not be able to access the correct child table.

Comment: I stated with how to skip ids and posted the main problem that may have nothing to do but some how is related to the issue, right know like everyone I'm in a hurry that's why I post all the problem. Regards

Comment: This is again something you need to look at differently, when users adding records to child tables, check for existance of that user in parent table, if the user exists fair enough let the insert proceed if user doesnt exist then rollback the transaction or add the user in parent table 1st and then let user add into child tables, again I dont know how this problem has come this far from the initial question.

Comment: don't worry you've already answer the question and it works, but i was trying to find out if there is a different way with the main issue. thank you

Comment: No I am not worried pal, I am trying to point you in the right direction or a possibly a better way to solve this problem. anyway not a problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you query the database to get the last inserted ID, then you can check if you need to increment it, by using a parameter in the query to set the correct ID.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to influence the AUTO_INCREMENT to "skip" a particular value, or values on a particular condition.

<strike>I think you'd have to handle this in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.</strike> An `AFTER INSERT` trigger can't update the values of the row that was just inserted, and I don't think it can make any modifications to the table affected by the statement that fired the trigger.

A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger won't work either, because the value assigned to an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is not available in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

---

I don't believe there's a way to get SQL Server `IDENTITY` to "skip" a particular value either.

---

**UPDATE**

If you need "unique" id values between two tables, there's a rather ugly workaround with MySQL: roll your own auto_increment behavior using triggers and a separate table. Rather than defining your tables with AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to obtain a value.

If an `id` value is supplied, and it's larger than the current maximum value from the auto_increment column in the dummy auto_increment_seq table, we'd need to either update that row, or insert a new one.

As a rough outline:

```
CREATE TABLE auto_increment_seq 
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT) ENGINE=MyISAM;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER TableNames_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON TableNames
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE li_new_id INT UNSIGNED;
   IF ( NEW.id = 0 OR NEW.id IS NULL ) THEN
      INSERT INTO auto_increment_seq (id) VALUES (NULL);
      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO li_new_id;
      SET NEW.id = li_new_id;
   ELSE
      SELECT MAX(id) INTO li_max_seq FROM auto_increment_seq;
      IF ( NEW.id > li_max_seq ) THEN
         INSERT INTO auto_increment_seq (id) VALUES (NEW.id);
      END IF;
   END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER TableNames_ai
AFTER INSERT ON TableNames
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE li_max_seq INT UNSIGNED;
   SELECT MAX(id) INTO li_max_seq FROM auto_increment_seq;
   IF ( NEW.id > li_max_seq ) THEN
      INSERT INTO auto_increment_seq (id) VALUES (NEW.id);
   END IF;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

The id column in the table could be defined something like this:

```
TableNames
( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 PRIMARY KEY 
    COMMENT 'populated from auto_increment_seq.id'
, ...
```

You could create an identical trigger for the other table as well, so the two tables are effectively sharing the same auto_increment sequence. (With less efficiency and concurrency than an Oracle `SEQUENCE` object would provide.)

**IMPORTANT NOTES**

This doesn't really insure that the `id` values between the tables are actually kept unique. That would really require a query of the other table to see if the id value exists or not; and if running with InnoDB engine, in the context of some transaction isolation levels, we might be querying a stale (as in, consistent from the point in time at the start of the transaction) version of the other table.

And absent some additional (concurrency killing) locking, the approach outline above is subject to a small window of opportunity for a "race" condition with concurrent inserts... the SELECT MAX() from the dummy seq table, followed by the INSERT, allows a small window for another transaction to also run a SELECT MAX(), and return the same value. The best we can hope for (I think) is for an error to be thrown due to a duplicate key exception.

This approach requires the dummy "seq" table to use the MyISAM engine, so we can get an Oracle-like AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION behavior; if inserts to the real tables are performed in the context of a REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level, reads of the MAX(id) from the seq table would be consistent from the snapshot at the beginning of the transaction, we wouldn't get the newly inserted (or updated) values.

We'd also really need to consider the edge case of an UPDATE of row changing the id value; to handle that case, we'd need BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE triggers as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **MSSQL**, you can do the following:

Before you insert check for the current ID, if it's 5, then do the following:

- Set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`
- Insert your data with ID = 7
- Set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `OFF`

Also you might get away with the following scenario:

- check for current ID
- if it's 5, run `DBCC CHECKIDENT (Table, reseed, 6)`, it will reseed the table and in this case your next identity will be 7

If you're checking for current identity just after INSERT, you can use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` or `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for better results (as rcdmk pointed out in comments)

Otherwise you can just use `select`: `SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table`

Comment: Sure it's obvious to us, but not to everyone accessing this page. ;)

Comment: you're right... I've edited the answer to make sure it's for MSSQL

Comment: Also, as we are still hot here, I'll give you a free hint: it's way better to use `scope_identity()` over `@@identity`, cause the later one can be affected by inserts done on triggers fired by the first query.